# Чем пустой конструктор по умолчанию отличается от =default;?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++-faq

Для конструктора по умолчанию,
чем пустое тело отличается от того что получается с `=default`?

```
X::X() {}
// и
X::X() = default;
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Наличие конструктора по умолчанию с пустым телом автоматически [**делает класс нетривиальным**](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/5IipVbUfiOn0oghf). Со всеми вытекающими отсюда особенностями. Например делает тип не [POD](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0_%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85). А также исключает возможность использовать агрегатную инициализацию:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

struct X {
    //X() {}
    X() = default;      
    int a;
    int b;
};

int main( ) {
    X x { 1, 2 }; // ошибка, если X - не тривиальный класс.
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << 
        std::is_trivial<X>::value << "\n"; 
}
```

При определении конструктора как `= default` тривиальность класса [сохраняется](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/hlN9ZnDPexodksQj), если она была до этого. В данном случае, это равносильно [отсутствию](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/2OohvW8YkOBS9sda) явного упоминания конструктора в определении класса.

Если конструктор по умолчанию определен как `= default` вне определения класса, всё равно будет считаться, что конструктор предоставлен пользователем, и это тоже [делает класс нетривиальным](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/bsdWwkWehKN73U7V).

Сноска на Стандарт по этому поводу (8.4.2/5):

> A function is *user-provided* if it is user-declared and not explicitly
>   defaulted or deleted on its first declaration.

---

Различие также будет наблюдаться при попытке создания константного объекта класса конструктором по умолчанию. Например:

```
const X x;
```

приведет к [ошибке](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/VRWRDwfR4tJjlfdU) компиляции при определении класса `X` как:

```
struct X {
    X() = default;
    int i;
};
```

И скомпилируется [удачно](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/68ZLMgiXJvMG066l) в случае предоставленного пользователем конструктора по умолчанию:

```
struct X {
    X() {}
    int i;
};
```

---

Еще один момент, демонстрирующий различие, возникает при использовании пустого списка инициализации при определении объекта. Например:

```
X x = { };
```

приведёт к обнулению всех членов класса при `= default` или отсутствующем явно конструкторе. Если же конструктор будет определён с пустым телом, то такая запись оставит члены класса неинициализированными (мусор).

Comment: Добавлю, что с C++20 [понятие POD стало deprecated](https://wg21.link/p0767).

Answer (score 20):

Определение с `=default;`, как и отсутствие определения (неявное определение) означает что компилятор сам должен подобрать подходящую реализацию.
В частности компилятор может определить функцию удаленной:

```
struct X {
  int& r;
  // X() {}       // ошибка, "r" не инициализрована
  X() = default;  // OK, компилятор сгенерирует X() = delete; (sic!)
                  // ссылка r не позволяет сгенерировать конструктор по умолчанию.
  X(int& r) : r(r) {}
};
```

Это мало полезно в обычном коде, но может пригодиться внутри шаблона - в зависимости от типов членов класса, компилятор сам выберет надо ли делать конструктор или удалить его.