# C++ добавление (= default/delete) в конце функции

Tags: c++

Описывается, что если указать `void func() = delete/default`, то это указывает, что компилятор сам должен сгенерировать код для этой функции и именно он будет использоваться.

Момент с генерацией кода компилятором совсем не понятный. 
Может кто объяснить доступным языком, что именно за код будет сгенерирован, что это означает и что использовалось до того как появились `= default/delete`? 
кроме того, если я допишу в конце деструктора `= default`, это будет означать, что он виртуальный?

Comment: http://archive.kalnytskyi.com/2012/01/23/introduction-to-cpp11-new-specifiers/

Comment: Связанный вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/495342

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Определение функции как `default` возможно только для специальных функций-членов класса: конструкторов, деструкторов и операторов присваивания. Определяться эти функции будут так, как они *неявно* определялись испокон веков - через делегирование соответствующих действий каждому полю класса. Произвольную постороннюю функцию нельзя просто взять и определить, как `default`.

Польза от возможности такого определения происходит в первую очередь из того, что в С++11 явное объявление перемещающего конструктора копирования или оператора присваивания подавляет неявное объявление/определение всех остальных функций из Правила Пяти (и наоборот). А в будущем объявление вообще любой функции из Правила Пяти будет подавлять объявление всех остальных функций Правила Пяти. Чтобы в такой ситуации "спасти" потерянные объявления/определения (если они вас устраивают) как раз и подходит `default`

```
struct S
{
  S& operator =(S &&) { return *this; }
  // Подавляет неявное объявление копирующего оператора присваивания
};

int main()
{
  S s, t;
  s = t; // Ошибка - нет копирующего оператора присваивания
}
```

Чтобы "восстановить" работоспособность этого кода достаточно добавить в класс

```
S& operator =(const S&) = default;
```

Некоторые тонкости зависят от того, где именно функция определена как `default`. Если такое определение сделано в точке первого объявления в классе, то такая функция ничем не отличается от неявно определенной функции - она не считается *предоставленной пользователем* (*user-provided*). А вот если функция была сначала объявлена в классе, а затем определена как `default` за пределами класса, то такая функция является *предоставленной пользователем*. Это влияет на такие свойства класса, как *агрегатность* и пр.

```
struct S
{
  int i;
  S() = default;
};

struct T
{
  int i;
  T();
};

T::T() = default; 

// Класс `S` по-прежнему является агрегатом, а вот класс `T`
// агрегатом не является

int main()
{
  S s = { 1 }; // Все в порядке, обычная агрегатная инициализация
  T t = { 1 }; // Ошибка, агрегатная инициализация недоступна
}
```

Описание деструктора как `default` никак не влияет на его виртуальность.

Определение как `delete` возможно для любых функций, но с этим такого вопроса не возникает.

Comment: теперь более понятно. спасибо.