# uniform-инициализация полей класса/структуры с++

Tags: c++, классы, структуры, инициализация

Есть вот такая структура:

```
struct Point
{
    float x;
    float y;
}
```

Когда мы создаем экземпляр этой структуры, мы можем сделать так:

```
Point a{1, 2};
```

Насколько я знаю, есть такая штука, как конструктор по умолчанию. Не значит ли это, что этот конструктор имеет такой вид:

```
Point(float x, float y)
{
   this->x = x;
   this->y = y;
}
```

Что и позволяет нам провести такую инициализацию.
Add:
При этом когда мы уже сами определяем любой конструктор, кроме выше показанного, мы уже не можем так инициализировать объект, что и наводит меня на такие мысли. Не могли бы вы мне про это подробнее рассказать?

Comment: проверял на разность, `Point a{1, 2};` - 61кб, а конструктор - 60 кб

Comment: значит, это две разные вещи

Comment: конструктор по умолчанию - это конструктор без параметров

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Конструктор по умолчанию - это конструктор, у которого нет параметров (или параметры имеют значения по умолчанию). Конструктор с двумя параметрами в вашем случае не является конструктором по умолчанию.

То что происходит при записи `Point a{1, 2};` называется [агрегатная инициализация](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.aggr). Она доступна в случаях, когда нет пользовательского конструктора у типа. Чуть подробнее можно почитать [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/495385/176217).

Comment: аггрегатная инициализация доступна когда нет **никаких** конструкторов и нет приватных ни защищённых членов и нет вирутальных методов и т.д.